# Classification of free $S^1$-actions on $S^2\times S^1$

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Consider smooth and free actions of the circle $S^1$ on the manifold $S^2\times S^1$. Are there any known classification of these up to equivariant diffeomorphism? One example of such an action is by simply letting the $S^1$ act in the obvious way on the $S^1$ factor, and leaving the $S^2$ factor intact. Could it possibly be the case that this is the only action (up to equivariant diffeomorphism)?

Answer (score 2):

Only one. One way to see this is to note that such an action on a manifold $M$ amounts to giving $M$ structure of a principal $S^1$-bundle. It is easy to see that in the case $M=S^2\times S^1$ the base has to be $S^2$. Now, use the classification of $S^1$ bundles over $S^2$ in terms of their Euler classes to conclude that the bundle has to be trivial.

You can find this type of arguments (and more) in any book dealing with "Seifert manifolds" (say, Orlik's). One can prove even more, that there is only one circle foliation on $S^2\times S^1$, given by a free circle action, up to isotopy.

Comment: @JasonDeVito I was sloppy: The circle  foliations are isotopic.

Comment: Why does the base have to be $S^2$? I understand everything else in your argument.

Comment: @user918673 The base has to be orientable since the total space is. If the base has positive genus, then it is aspherical, and so is the total space, which is not the case here.

Comment: Here I am using the long exact sequence of homotopy groups of a fibration.